# How make sortable only for one child

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, drag-and-drop, jquery-ui-selectable

I have an div in which I want to put only one children. That is, after the position of the element, turn off the property sortable and turn it on again after moving his child [source code,if you change the code to a working one, I will be grateful](https://codepen.io/iamgafurov/pen/vYLMYMo). Thsnks!

```
    <div id = "events" class = "dragable">
      <div id="event1" data="event1" class="task task--primary li">Event 1</div>
      <div id="event2" data="event2" class="task task--primary li">Event 2</div>
      <div id="event3" data="event3" class="task task--primary li">Event 3</div>
      <div id="event4" data="event4" class="task task--primary li">Event 4</div>
      <div id="event5" data="event5" class="task task--primary li">Event 5</div> 
      <div id="event6" data="event6" class="task task--primary li">Event 6</div>
    </div>
    </div>
 </div> 
<div class="calendar-container col"> 
    <div class="calendar"><span class="day-name">Mon</span><span class="day-name">Tue</span><span class="day-name">Wed</span><span class="day-name">Thu</span><span class="day-name">Fri</span><span class="day-name">Sat</span><span class="day-name">Sun</span>
    <div class="day " id="day1">
    <div class="dragable event-container" border=1></div>
    <div class="dragable event-container" border=1></div>
    <div class="dragable event-container" border=1></div>   
    <div class="dragable event-container" border=1></div>
    <div class="dragable event-container" border=1></div>
    <div class="dragable event-container" border=1></div>
    </div>
```

```
   $(".dragable").sortable({connectWith:".dragable",
    stop: function() {
      
    }
   });
}) 
function saveTimetable(){
  var day1=[],day3=[],day2=[],day4=[],day5=[],day6=[],day7=[];
  for(let j=1;j<8;j++){
  var obj=$("#day"+ j).children();
  for(let i=0;i<obj.length;i++)
    {
      if(typeof obj.eq(i).children().eq(0).attr("data") !="undefined")   console.log("day: "+j,"item:"+i,"data: " + obj.eq(i).children().eq(0).attr("data"));
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: It's still unclear from your code and post what your objective is. Please see this example: https://jqueryui.com/draggable/#sortable Please edit your post and clarify what it is you want to accomplish. Please add anything you have tried or what you have found that does not work.

Comment: @twisty 
what you don't understand? 
I want each div to be able to put only one elemnt

Comment: @Twisty sorry I'm write selectable in place sortable(